# Angular 5 styling elements within component without scope

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component which is embedding a Microsoft PowerBI Report. The `powerbi-client` takes a `nativeElement` from a `ElementRef` and injects an iframe with the embedded report. I want to style the border (remove it) on the iframe itself. The issue is Angular CLI is encapsulating the SCSS but the PowerBI library is injecting the iframe, so angular doesn't 'know about it', thus no encapsulation attributes on element e.g. `_ngcontent-c8`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  template: `
  <div style="height:100%; width: 100%;" class="powerbi-frame" #frame></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() accessToken: string;
  @Input() embedUrl: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @ViewChild('frame') frame: ElementRef;

  private _report: pbi.Report;
  private _reportloaded = false;
  constructor( @Inject('PowerBIClientService') private _client: pbi.service.Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const config: pbi.IEmbedConfiguration = {
      accessToken: this.accessToken,
      tokenType: pbi.models.TokenType.Embed,
      embedUrl: this.embedUrl,
      type: 'report',
      id: this.id,
      settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: false
      }
    };

    this._report = this._client.embed(this.frame.nativeElement, config) as pbi.Report;

    this._report.on('loaded', ev => this._reportloaded = true);
  }
}
```

*report.component.scss*

```
.powerbi-frame iframe {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}
```

I am looking for a way to do something like:

```
.powerbi-frame :no-encapsulation(iframe) {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}
```

Which should generate something along the lines of:

```
.powerbi-frame[_nghost-c8] iframe { <-- note no scoping on iframe selector
  border-width: 0px; 
  border-style: none; 
}
```

I understand I could put these rules in my main styles.scss, but that seems like kind of a hack. Can anyone point me toward a more correct way of achieving styling an unscoped element within an angular component?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to mix the css encapsulation as you are wanting. You could possibly grab the unique identifier from one of your component's elements and manually add it to the iframe element. However this feels more hacky to me than defining a global class.

Comment: Did you try `/deep/`?

Comment: @estus: That works actually, but is marked as deprecated in Angular's docs. Any idea if they're replacing it with something functionally equivalent?

Comment: I don't think that /deep/ will go away in near future. Since it isn't natively supported any way, you can use ::ng-deep synonym. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867 .

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation). If you do not want style encapsulation then add the following to your `@Component` definition:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  template: `
  <div style="height:100%; width: 100%;" class="powerbi-frame" #frame></div>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: But that makes any rules specified in my component apply globally. I can "work around" that, yes, but it doesn't seem to be a terribly good method as application complexity grows.